# laravel nested foreach loop generating duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this method returns json response. each order has many products and i want product key in data array has products names related to that order.

```
$customerData = Order::whereAdminId($this->admin->id)->whereCustomerId($customer->id)->
whereBetween('created_at', array($date_from,$date_to))->get();

if (count($customerData) > 0) {
    $data1 = array();
    $data3 = array();
    foreach ($customerData as $value) {
        foreach ($value->orderProducts as $value1) {            
            $data3[] = array($value1->products($value1->product_id)->name);
        }
        $data[] = array(
            'product'=>$data3, 
        );
    }
    return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'customerData'=>$data], 200);
}
```

but on nested foreach previous values add to new values and all products names duplicate for each order. thanks

Comment: Did you tried  `array_push()` on `$data3` assignment

Comment: yes duplicates again

Comment: can you post the $data?

Comment: this method search customer orders when return object in post mode  it works on blade template fine. but to create array for ajax response, duplicate values